# How to convert the jsonStr to Observable<T> when use Retrofit

Tags: retrofit, fastjson

I wrote a Interface for Retrofit,

```
public interface MyService {
    @POST("/api/index")
    <T> Observable<T> doRequest(@Body Object request);
}
```

then build the service,

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint("http://localtest.com")
        .setConverter(new FastJsonConverter())
        .setRequestInterceptor(new CookiesInterceptor(LApplication.getInstance()))
        .build();
this.service = restAdapter.create(MyService.class);
```

when I do request:

```
Observable<Response> resp = service.doRequest(getRequest())
resp.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(maoApi.mSubscriber);
```

but the converter cannot converjson to Response Object?

I print out the `Type in FastJsonConverter:fromBody(TypedInput body, Type type)`
the type is `T`.

also when use Gson , is still has this problem...

How to solve this problem? or is my design is uncorrect?

Comment: I don't think you can use Retrofit with generics, see https://github.com/square/retrofit/commit/15b306a767d747063a34fc66d24e316630a5151d

Comment: I am quite sure there is now way for Retrofit to know that you declared `resp` as an `Observable<Response>` - in fact, you didn't even need to store the return value of `doRequest` in *any* variable. Why do you want to use generics in that case - is there any chance that `/api/index` would return anything other than a `Response`?

Comment: In my project, when send a Object to server ,the server will return a Object. like `LoginRequest { String name;String password; }` and return `LoginResponse{ String result; String token;}`. Or other Request `UserRequest {String uid; }` return `UserResponse{User mUser;}`... so, I want to use generics..